# Expansion coefficients in multipole expansion as spherical tensors

Tags: representation-theory, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

This is a relatively simple question, but I cannot find a clear answer:

Given the multipole expansion of a *real* scalar function,
$$
f(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{\lambda\mu} f_{\lambda\mu}(r) Y_{\lambda\mu}(\theta,\phi)
$$
do the coefficient functions $f_{\lambda\mu}(r)$ necessarily form spherical tensors of rank $\lambda$? It seems plausible that they do (or that they form contragradient tensors) since the sum over $\mu$ looks an awful lot like a scalar contraction.